# PUSH-000503: MultiplexerBlockedException while calling Client.isSubscribed

Tags: java, push-diffusion

Some times I am getting following exception while checking isSubscribed with some topic.

Checking condition : `Client.isSubscribed(topic)`

Exception : `com.pushtechnology.diffusion.multiplexer.MultiplexerBlockedException`

Comment: Prasath can you detail in your question which version are you using? A log snippet showing the error in context is useful too.

Comment: I am using diffusion-5.5.6.jar.                                                           Exception in thread "HeartbeatTimer" com.pushtechnology.diffusion.multiplexer.MultiplexerBlockedException: Multiplexer blocked
 at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.multiplexer.MultiplexerManagerImpl.map(MultiplexerManagerImpl.java:287)
 at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.api.internal.topic.TopicImpl.getClients(TopicImpl.java:745)
 at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.publisher.BasePublisher.getClients(BasePublisher.java:1246)
 at com.pushtechnology.diffusion.api.publisher.Publisher.getClients(Publisher.java:1071)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception manifests in `logs/Server.log` as `PUSH-000503` with description

```
A blocking operation failed because the multiplexers failed to process it within {} milliseconds
```

The default value for that timeout is 30s, which is a lifetime for a multiplexer to wait. [The manual says the following: "This indicates that the server is severely overloaded or deadlocked"](http://docs.pushtechnology.com/docs/5.7.2/manual/html/administratorguide/systemmanagement/logging/logs/PUSH-000503.html).

On another note, version v5.5 is unsupported, and you are advised to upgrade before attempting a reproduction.